# centralizar formulário verticalmente ao centro

Tags: html, css

Estou finalizando um site e o formulário tem que esta centralizado verticalmente na página.

Já tentei de tudo pra ter uma margem em % mas nenhuma técnica funciona. já botei `%`, botei como *absolute to top* e nada.

Vou deixar o link do beta para vocês darem um olhada e me darem uma luz.

http://bblender.com.br/clientes/moldin/contato

Código pessoal

```
<section class="container">
   <h2>CONTATO</h2>
       <form id="form-contato" action="contato/send" method="post" name="contato" >     
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
       </form>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
</section>

.container{
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#form-contato {color: #58595B;margin-top: 13%;}
```

Answer (score 1):

olha o seguinte exemplo:

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}

#form-contato {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;    

    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <h2>CONTATO</h2>
    <form id="form-contato" action="contato/send" method="post" name="contato" >
        <label for="txtTeste" >Teste:</label>
        <input is="txtTeste" type="text" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/0nh8ms29/3/

Comment: rman, só funciona com o position:absolute?

Comment: @LuisFernandoMangia utilizando esta abrodagem sim, pois o form está centralizado em relação ao browser e não ao container.

Answer (score 0):

Você só precisa alterar uma regra de margem no seu id `#form-contato`:

```
#form-contato {
  color: #58595B;
  margin: 13% 0
}
```

Isso vai fazer com que o mesmo tenha margem de 13% tanto na parte inferior quanto superior.
Resultado: [atual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOGHg.jpg) | [com a alteração](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnlQe.jpg).